# Show image background after video background autoplay

Tags: html, video, background

I want to show a photo background after the video background is played; I have tried by adding a background image in the css but at the end of the video, the image is now shown.

Here is the code:

```
<video id="my-video" class="video" autoplay>
  <source src="media/demo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="media/demo.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="media/demo.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>

<script>
  (function() {
    /**
     * Video element
     * @type {HTMLElement}
    */
    var video = document.getElementById("my-video");

    /**
     * Check if video can play, and play it
    */
    video.addEventListener("canplay", function() {
      video.play();
    });
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried adding a listener for "ended" and hide the video element and show the image?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the video `ended` event and replace the `<video>` element with a `<img>` element.

```
video.addEventListener("ended",function(){
  //For example:
  video.classList.add("hide");
  backgroundImg.classList.remove("hide");
});
```